# How to run virtual keyboard on macOS (Catalina / Big Sur)

Tags: macos, command-line, system

I can run virtual keyboard app in macOS Sierra but not in Catalina and Big Sur.

Are there any alternative available to launch virtual keyboard from terminal.

[image: macOS Sierra keyboard]